# Error trying to load accuracy metric with evaluate

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, evaluate, huggingface

I'm trying to train a GPT-2 model using an example script from Huggingface Transformer Github and I get an error when the scripts tries to load 'accuracy' metric:

`evaluate.load("accuracy")`

File "/home/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/loading.py", line 752, in load
evaluation_instance = evaluation_cls(
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I tried to load other metrics and I only get error with accuracy

I've got installed the requirements:

- scikit-learn 1.3.dev0
- evaluate 0.4.1.dev0

I'm running the run_clm.py script example for language modeling.

Is there something I need to install besides scikit-learn and evaluate? Is there something wrong with the library?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the full error trace. Also, what is the run_clm.py script? Could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I update the version of evaluate from "evaluate 0.1.2" to "evaluate 0.4.0", and solved it